# Add a ScrollView in Linear and Relative Layout in one XML file

Tags: android, android-layout

I am trying to make the contents of Relative Layout as Scrollview as its not fitting in the screen. My XML file that consists of both, Linear and Relative Layout where Linear  is acting as Parent and Relative as child layout.

Although I have browsed, most of the questions regarding this topic, but all i could find is how to insert Scrollview in Linear or Relative Layout respectively but not when both layouts are in one file.

my XML file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<!-- 
   Being of Linear Layout
 -->

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/week1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/week1"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        android:paddingTop="50dp"
        android:background="#00141c" />
<!--
Begin Relative Layout
-->

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:scrollHorizontally="true">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/treadmillimage"
        android:layout_width="115dp"
        android:layout_height="93dp"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:src="@drawable/treadmill" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/durOnTreadmill"
        android:layout_width="129dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:layout_marginLeft="180dp" 
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"/>

<!--
End Relative Layout
-->
    </RelativeLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/treadmilltext"
        android:layout_width="91dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:text="@string/treadmill"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

<!--
Begin Relative Layout
-->

    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:scrollHorizontally="true">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/stepperimage"
        android:layout_width="115dp"
        android:layout_height="93dp"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:src="@drawable/stepper" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/durOnStepper"
        android:layout_width="129dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:layout_marginLeft="180dp" 
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"/>

<!--
End Relative Layout
-->
    </RelativeLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/steppertext"
        android:layout_width="91dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:text="@string/stepper"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

<!--
Begin Relative Layout
-->
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:scrollHorizontally="true">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/stationaryrowing"
        android:layout_width="115dp"
        android:layout_height="93dp"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:src="@drawable/stationaryrowing" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/durOnStationaryRowing"
        android:layout_width="129dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:layout_marginLeft="180dp" 
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"/>

<!--
End Relative Layout
-->
    </RelativeLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/stationaryrowingtext"
        android:layout_width="91dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:text="@string/stationaryrowing"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

<!--
Begin Relative Layout
-->
     <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:scrollHorizontally="true">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/exercisebikeimage"
        android:layout_width="115dp"
        android:layout_height="93dp"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:src="@drawable/excerisebike" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/durOnexcerisebike"
        android:layout_width="129dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:layout_marginLeft="180dp" 
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"/>

 <!--
End Relative Layout
-->
    </RelativeLayout>

     <TextView
        android:id="@+id/excerisebiketext"
        android:layout_width="91dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:text="@string/exercisebike"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

 <!--
Begin Relative Layout
-->
       <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:scrollHorizontally="true">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ellipticaltrainerimage"
        android:layout_width="115dp"
        android:layout_height="93dp"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ellipticaltrainer" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/durOnellipticaltrainer"
        android:layout_width="129dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:layout_marginLeft="180dp" 
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"/>

<!--
End Relative Layout
-->
    </RelativeLayout>

        <TextView
        android:id="@+id/ellipticaltrainertext"
        android:layout_width="91dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:text="@string/ellipticaltrainer"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

<!--
End Linear Layout
-->
</LinearLayout>
```

All the contents below **TextView of Week 1** are required to be in Scrollview

Thanks in advance, will really appreciate all the answers :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just put the scorolleview as parent of the RelativeLayout as follows:

```
<ScrollView 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<RelativeLayout 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:scrollHorizontally="true">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/treadmillimage"
        android:layout_width="115dp"
        android:layout_height="93dp"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:src="@drawable/treadmill" />

.....
.....
</RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: It throws an exception, "Exception raised during rendering: ScrollView can host only one direct child"

Comment: you are making a mistake.just close the crollview before LinearLayout and after RelativeLayout. got it ?Also i edited the answer a little.Remove xmlns from SrollView.

Comment: As you can see I have several Relative Layouts (4 in total). If i close the scrollview at the end of the first one, Based on my knowledge it will only be applied on the first one. However, i want to make all 4 Relative Layout scroll together. If i close the scrollview just above the end tag of Linear Layout it throws the same exception.

Comment: No, just remove xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" from every RelativeLayout and try.

Comment: Thanks mate, It worked like a pro :). I thought you meant remove that line from ScrollView.

Comment: No Problem.Welcome and happy to help you.Keep smiling. :)

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want the topmost `TextView` to be part of the scrolling area, then you'll have to nest the `RelativeLayout`s into another layout, because a `ScrollView` can have only one direct child.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView ... />

    <ScrollView ... >
        <!-- only one direct child for scrollview: -->
        <LinearLayout ... >

            <RelativeLayout ... />
            <TextView ... />
            <RelativeLayout ... />
            <TextView ... />
            <RelativeLayout ... />
            <TextView ... />
            <RelativeLayout ... />
            <TextView ... />
            <!-- etc -->

        </LinearLayout>

    </ScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```